# NSSharingService fill "To:" field in message composer

Tags: macos, operating-system, imessage

is it possible to fill in receiver phone number (apple id) in message composer to share smth via [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNameComposeMessage] ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `recipients` property of NSSharingService. It is an array that you can fill with multiple receivers.

```
let service = NSSharingService(named: NSSharingServiceNameComposeMessage)

let items = [<someItems>] as [AnyObject]
service?.recipients = ["mail@provider.com", ...]
service?.delegate = self
service?.performWithItems(items)
```